# Using react mobx actions from another stores inside components and other stores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, mobx

in my react native app I want to use mobx for state management, my store is divided in multiple stores/files and since I want to be able to call a store actions from another stores I'm implementing a GlobalStore where I instantiate the other stores.

I want to be able to do something like this from my components

```
import { PostStore }  from '../stores/PostStore.js'
import { UserStore }  from '../stores/UserStore.js'
import { VenueStore }  from '../stores/VenueStore.js'


class GlobalStore
{
    
    postStore = new PostStore(this);
    userStore = new UserStore(this);
    venueStore = new VenueStore(this);

}

export default new GlobalStore;
```

This makes it so that using react-native Context-Provider API I can call every store action in ALL my compoennts using globalStore as a link:

In any component I can do:

```
globalStore.postStore.listPosts()
```

However I'm still not sure how I can access other store actions from within OTHER STORES.

What if inside postStore I want to use spinnerStore (to show axios calls pending, error or success status):

```
@action.bound getPosts = flow(function * (payload) 
    {
        this.spinnerStore.setData({status: 1});
        try 
        {
            this.spinnerStore.setData({status: 2, response: response});
            let response = yield axios.get('/api/posts', { params: payload })
            return response;
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            this.spinnerStore.setData({ status: 3, errors: error });
            throw error;
        }
    })
```

Here spinnerStore would be undefined...

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm still not sure how I can access other store actions from within OTHER STORES.

When you instantiate a store you can assign one of its properties to be another store instance. This is what you included in your example

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(instance) {
    this.instance = instance
  }
}

class Bar {}

const foo = new Foo(new Bar());

foo.instance instanceof Bar; // true
```

Now your `foo` instance has access to any public properties/methods defined on `Bar`

```
class Foo {
  constructor(instance) {
    this.instance = instance
  }
}

class Bar {
  @observable isLoading = false;
  @observable data = null;

  @action
  getData() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    return axios.get('/foo').then((data) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.data = data;
    }).catch(e => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}

const foo = new Foo(new Bar());

// in react
const MyComponent = ({ foo }) => (
  <div>
    {foo.instance.isLoading && <Spinner />}

    <button onClick={foo.instance.getData}>
     will call Bar action from Foo store
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default lodash.flowRight(
  mobx.inject((stores) => ({ foo: stores.fooStore })),
  mobx.observer
)(MyComponent)
```

In your example with generators, you cannot use fat arrows so `this` isn't bound to your class instance anymore, which is why it will be undefined. Using promises and fat arrows solves that problem.